# What could be best design to create codedui tests for a big project

Tags: oop, coded-ui-tests, ui-testing

I want to create codedui tests for a project having multiple views. The directory structure is as follows:

1. Dir1

   - Dir1 View1
   - Dir1 View2
2. Dir2

   - Dir2 View1
   - Dir2 View2
3. Dir3

   - Dir3 View1
   - Dir3 View2

I want to use the record tool to identify and save elements and then use them to hand code tests. 
I guess i would be better to create separate UIMaps for all the views as follows:

1. Dir1

   - UIMap11
   - UIMap12
2. Dir2

   - UIMap21
   - UIMap22
   - CommonScenarios.cs
3. Dir3

   - UIMap31
   - UIMap32
   - CommonFunctions.cs

But i'm not getting how to run all the tests from a single CodedUITest.cs file which was created when i created the project.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `.cs` files. Make each file contain a different class with the `[CodedUITest]` attribute and the method for each test in those classes have the `[TestMethod]` attribute. You then expect Visual Studio to find all the tests in all of those classes.

I recommend that each test method is given a different name as the "Test Explorer" window shows test names but not classes.